# Disable Implicit Deref Coercions

Tags: rust

My question here is quite specific.  *I want to disable implicit deref coercions* (let's say because I don't like them).  More specifically, I want this code to fail:

```
fn main() {
    let x = Box::new(0);
    let mut y = &x;
    y = &mut y;
    println!("GOT {}",*y);
}
```

To my mind, this is a pretty nonsensical example.  But, it compiles because (I believe) `&mut T` coerces to `T` and, hence, the statement `y = &mut y` is a nop.

Assuming this is right, *how do I prevent Rust from doing this?*  I tried, for example, using `#[no_implicit_prelude]` but with no joy.

Comment: I'm highly doubtful that it's possible to disable, as it's a core language feature. It's kind of like asking how to disable `for` loops.

Comment: The code you have presented does not use auto-deref. The type of `*y` is `Box<i32>`, and the `Display` formatting for `Box` is just to print its contents.

Comment: It's not clear *what* you are trying to disable here or why you'd think disabling the prelude would work.

Comment: Disabling the prelude is an attempt to prevent the `Deref` trait from being included.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have given does not actually use any auto-dereferencing. The type of `y` is `&Box<i32>` and the `println` works because the `Display` formatting for `Box` is to just delegate to its contents `Display` implementation.

If I change your example slightly, we can bring auto-dereferencing into play:

```
fn main() {
    let x = Box::new(0);
    let mut y: &i32 = &x; // <-- Deref impl is used here
    y = &mut y;
    println!("GOT {}", y);
}
```

You cannot disable any traits that are implemented for built-in types. You could make your own `Box` that doesn't implement `Deref`:

```
use std::{boxed, fmt};

struct Box<T>(boxed::Box<T>);

impl<T> Box<T> {
    pub fn new(value: T) -> Self {
        Self(boxed::Box::new(value))
    }
}

impl<T: fmt::Display> fmt::Display for Box<T> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.0)
    }
}
```

Auto-dereferencing does not work:

```
fn main() {
    let x = Box::new(0);
    let mut y: &i32 = &x; // <-- Error:  expected `i32`, found struct `Box`
    y = &mut y;
    println!("GOT {}", y);
}
```

But you can still print the box itself:

```
fn main() {
    let x = Box::new(0);
    let mut y = &x; 
    y = &mut y;
    println!("GOT {}", y); // y: &Box<i32>
}
```

I'm not sure why you would do this though. You will have to re-implement **a lot** of `Box` functionality to make this generally useful, and it isn't at all clear what are the advantages of not having a `Deref` impl.

Comment: In fact, the OP wants no deref at all, so all the types that implement `Deref` must be rewritten.

Comment: You are technically correct, but the OP's example is confusing things by using `Box`. There is a deref coercion happening in the line `y = &mut y`, but you couldn't "fix" it by reimplementing `Box` because it's actually the `Deref` impl for `&mut T` that applies.

Comment: Not sure this is achieving what I want, though appreciate what I want is not obvious.  As @trentcl says this answer isn't fixing `y = &mut y` which is actually the line I care about.  In the end, the answer seems to be that you can't disable deref coercion on primitive types.  I thought there might be some include magic such as `#[no_deref_coercion]` which would I wasn't aware of.  I think we shouldn't worry too much about _why_ I want to do this ... it's for a very strange reason (think academic experiment).